# what are the correct parameters for Instantiate a TCP Socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I need to create an instance of Socket class ,  But i am not sure what parameters should I parse to create  TCP socket ,

```
    System.Net .Sockets .Socket s = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket
 (//what are the parameters required in here ?")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tcp :

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
   SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

For Udp :

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
   SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
```

The above code example shows you have to instantiate a socket in either way